# Flutter - How to get text form field on error text with icon

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, textfield

I try to implemnt the validation error message but, Based on on my UI i need to implement the text with icon, i search online i fond errorborder but not icon besed of errortext. How to implement the validation error text with icon?

```
TextField(
                        autocorrect: true,
                        autofocus: false,
                        controller: reasonController,
                        style: textfieldlableStyle,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        maxLines: 10,
                        maxLength: null,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          hintText: "I’m canceling because",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "regular",
                              color: MyColors.fieldLabel,
                              fontSize: 16),
                          focusedBorder: null,
                          errorBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 1,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              )),
                          errorText: _cancelValidate ? 'Details can\'t be Empty' : null,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4, top: 0),
                        )),
```

[I want this type of implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDKdV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicodes here

```
errorText: _cancelValidate ? '\u24d8 Details can\'t be Empty' : null,
```